# JayStorm data services insert/update/delete/query interception

Tags: jaydata

If I wanted to inject some code in to my odata insert/update/delete/query end points is there a way to do this?

For example:

- On query I want to inject a security based further restraint (like if role is x then return subset of data).
- On update I want to prevent certain fields from being updated (like CreateDate), so some form of overpost protection.  Or I want to not allow a regular user update administrative data columns.
- On insert/update I want to have server based logic calculate certain column values and further more trigger certain server operations.
- On delete I want to cancel the delete, insert the record in to an audit table and set the DeleteDate column of the entity - AKA soft delete.

Are these possible?  Any documents/tutorials on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We do not have column level security, only table level.
However you can achieve what you want using before/after events, like beforeCreate, beforeUpdate, where you can insert your server side javascript code to intervene.

Comment: Oh - that's great that those events exist.  I am new to JayStorm - can you be kind enough to direct me to a place where I can read about this?  Or maybe a sample?  Can I get access to the logged in user's identity and his/her roles in those functions and run different code paths based on that?

Comment: Hi, we'll have a blogpost about it soon.

Comment: Very nice writeup.  Thanks.  Please do consider first class support for cancelling a delete in beforedelete (My understanding is that it can't be done right now?)

Comment: sure you can, just return false

Comment: Ah - that's great.  So for soft delete I can update the DeletedOn date column to the current tie and update the record but return false so the delete is canceled (and effectively turned into an update)?

Comment: in the event handler you can do strange things but it does not mean that you should

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the latest blogpost about the [event handlers in JayData](http://jaydata.org/blog/jaydata-event-handlers) - the Entity
The before/after EntitySet-level events are the ones you can customize on JayStorm PaaS application manager.

**Implementing role-based behavior:**
The 'this' variable contains a user, which you can use to implement custom logic.

```
var self = this; //it's better to avoid confusions later
var currentUser = self.User;
```

Checking user group membership:

```
if (currentUser.Groups.indexOf('admin') <0 ){
  items.forEach(function(it)){
    //items is an array of created/updated/deleted entities
  }
}
```

**Properties of the user:**
Groups - returns an array of strings
Login, FirstName, LastName, Enabled, Password

**Softdelete**
This requires custom development. I recommend you to disallow the delete action to the security groups and publish a service method to provide this functionality.